# Sobel or Isotropic Sobel or Sotropic Sobel

Tags: matlab, opencv

I was reading from a paper related to Sobel but I couldn't find much info about any about isotropic or sotropic Sobel. Is it the same thing as Sobel?

Somehow from the paper I read the masks used for sotropic sobel is like this:

[image]

Somehow it's a bit different from the original Sobel. http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/sobel.htm

Comment: The sobel kernel is the differentiation operator essentially (using finite difference). By using the square root you essentially decrease the sensitivity of the derivative to the elements directly left and right of the pixel in question. The definition of isotropic is "uniformity in all orientations" so it's sort of equalizing the weights I guess.

Comment: Decrease its sensitivity means?Less sensitive to detect the edges?

Comment: @jucestain Your comment could easily be an answer. It's clear and concise.